# KeyError: 'access_token'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When i try to run this code

```
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import requests, gspread
import os
import ast

def authenticate_google_docs():
    f = open(os.path.join('Checkin.p12'), 'rb')
    SIGNED_KEY = f.read()
    f.close()
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://docs.google.com/feeds']
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials('danylo.lian@gmail.com', SIGNED_KEY, scope)

    data = {
        'refresh_token' : '<refresh-token-copied>',
        'client_id' : '<client-id-copied>',
        'client_secret' : '<client-secret-copied>',
        'grant_type' : 'refresh_token',
    }

    r = requests.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', data = data)
    credentials.access_token = ast.literal_eval(r.text)['access_token']

    gc = gspread.authorize(credentials)
    return gc

gc = authenticate_google_docs()

sh = gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11WR6rwQhL4wUDN8I77ju_5rzZl8IglsUjtUDI6pZsAQ/edit#gid=0')
```

I got an error

> credentials.access_token = ast.literal_eval(r.text)['access_token']
>   KeyError: 'access_token'

What does it means and what must i do?

Comment: KeyError says you that `credentials` list hasn't got 'access_token' key. That's all I can say about it.

Comment: But how to add access_token to credentials?

Comment: Oops, I get mistake. `ast.literal_eval(r.text)` hasn't got 'access_token' key.

Comment: But how to change it?

Comment: Print out `r.text` to find out what's there.

Comment: It is writing that same error

Comment: Print it before trying to use it and tell us what the output is.